# How to get url segment params from a given url outside of a controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Given a path such as

```
/foos/123
```

and a route

```
get '/foos/:id', as: 'foos'
```

How to get the ID using Rails routes (reverse) look up?

In this example, `path.split('/').last` would work, and a regex would be better. But how to use the Rails routes to do it?

This functionality was provided by `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path` but has been deprecated.

Note: **This not part of a controller.** Please do not answer about how to use routes within a controller.

Rails 6.

Comment: I don't think `recognize_path` was ever part of the public API and meant to be used. Maybe I'm wrong, but since this was deprecated I don't think there is other way than you just described with parsing raw URL/pah. Great question, up.

Comment: You have told us that the context is not a controller, what is it then?

Comment: @max -  It is a model.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Routing is actually a lot more complicated than that.

The routes are not just a simple static set of regexes that match a string to a controller and action. You need an entire request object. You have to remember that constraints put things like headers, cookies and even middleware like Warden in the picture.

`Rails.application.routes.recognize_path` was depreciated since it completely failed at handling this complexity. It just gave a false sense of simplicity which is probably the worst thing software can do.